# Settings IBOutlets to nil in dealloc

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management

In the section titled 'Memory Warnings' here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html, I don't follow why the IBOutlet is set to nil in the dealloc.  If

```
self.anOutlet = nil
```

causes a crash as mentioned in the topic, why are they setting the ivar to nil?

In general, why would you set an ivar to nil in the dealloc when you are already calling release?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a `release`, the pointer is essentially invalid and accessing it again may cause a crash.  By setting a variable to `nil` after `release` you prevent that crash from happening.  There's no harm in accessing a nil pointer.

The example you've linked to simply demonstrates why it's always a good idea to set a variable or ivar to `nil` after `release`, even when it looks like the variable/ivar won't be accessed again.

In the example, the `anOutlet` ivar is actually accessed by the superclass *after* your `dealloc` method, so if you don't set it to nil you will get a crash.  Scenarios like that are very hard to spot just by looking at the code, so it's a good idea to nil every variable after release, even in dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a message on an object that is released causes a crash, sending a message to a nil object is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a crash is a good thing, and a quick solution would hide a deeper problem. Calling a released variable might be something you want to know about.

The book *iOS Recipes* refers to this issue:

> **Cleanup in -dealloc**
>   In addition to releasing all relevant instance variables in the -dealloc, our examples set them to nil. This practice is one of the most hotly debated topics among Cocoa programmers, and both sides of the argu- ment hold weight. This book is not meant to participate in the debate at all: we set them to nil, but that doesn’t mean you have to. If you don’t like nil-in-dealloc, feel free to leave it out of your own code.

A quick google search found this thread:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/204055-why-should-we-set-ivars-to-nil-in-dealloc.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when one property becomes invalid (set to nil) we want to make other properties invalid too. If a class invalidates a property by using self.property_name=nil, then this will send a release message, which will cause a crash in dealloc if we have already called release on that property. If the invalidation occurs in a superclass, then this error is hidden and quite nasty. So whenever a superclass might invalidate a property it may be a good idea to set it to nil rather than just deallocing.