# IBOutlet collection release problem

Tags: iphone, arrays, release

I have an array for IBOutlet collection

.h

```
@interface UpisiRezultat : UIViewController {
    NSArray *buttons;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

.m

```
@synthesize buttons;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"NeverSayNever" size:22] forKeyPath:@"buttons.font"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    buttons = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [buttons release]; --> Error
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Why does my program crash when I have [buttons release]; in dealloc?
Without it, it doesn't crash...

Answer (score 2):

updated(Dec1) code and Tested.

```
- (void)dealloc {

    self.buttons = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

you should not release them.

http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/

Comment: so u didnt create array or connect with IB

Comment: it says: modifying layer that is being finalized

Comment: i created an array and connected it to outlets

Comment: self.buttons = nil;//in viewdidunload use with self.

Comment: tried to use self.buttons in viewDidUnload still crashes, the array is in plist.file, it's a font I'm using

Comment: The problem was that I put [buttons release]; 2 times in dealloc, idiot xD

Thanks guys!

Comment: but in ur above code u have only one release call . y?.so update code of original

Comment: I did just like you said - self.myObjects and everything works perfectly except one thing - when i do Product -> Analyze it tells me "incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller" pointing at the line where i release self.myObjects. Is it dangerous in any way? Should i fix it somehow?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Please post ur code . i can help u.because now i am free.and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you have made a connection to your buttons with Interface Builder, it's your view that owns it and will release it.

Comment: but it has retain in property

Comment: Yes it means that when IB add it to the view, He will use this property and call a retain on it. So you're safe.

Comment: So I don't need to release IBOutlets ever?

Answer (score 0):

Since buttons is an NSArray and it is explicitly retained, then it must be released and then set to nil in -dealloc.

See Darren's answer at: [Settings IBOutlets to nil in dealloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682080/settings-iboutlets-to-nil-in-dealloc)
See an IBOutletCollection example at: http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/.