# How to add objects to IBOutletCollection?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsarray, uilabel, iboutlet

I declared NSArray in my class

```
NSArray             *labelsArray;
```

I made it a property

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labelsArray;
```

I connected it to four UILabels in IB. I allocated the array. When i do this

```
NSLog(@"labelsArray.count %i",[labelsArray count]);
```

It tells me that labelsArray's count is 0. What should i do to actually add those labels to the array?

Comment: "I allocated the array" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: i mean i did labelsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I allocated the array.

It could be that the array is automatically instantiated for you when the NIB file is loaded and that reallocating it creates a new (empty) version of the array. Try not allocating it. Also make sure you NSLog the array in `viewDidLoad`, when the IB elements are loaded.

Comment: yep, without allocating the array's count is 4. Thank you very much once again

Comment: just one more question: should i release the array in dealloc or it's not necessary?

Comment: you should set it to nil via the accessor (self.labelsArray = nil;) in viewDidUnload and release it in dealloc.

Comment: are you sure? if i release the array my app crashes. if i don't it works all right

Comment: apparently you should set them to nil in dealloc also.

Comment: and another ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682080/settings-iboutlets-to-nil-in-dealloc

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling the NSLog statement?  The array will not be instantiated until viewDidLoad is called.